# how to make the Serialization of a Dict of models

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have to serialize a Dict of Models with django rest framework

/Serializers.py :

```
class MapFilterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    bedroom_1 = ProjectsSerializer(many=True)
    bedroom_2 = ProjectsSerializer(many=True)
    bedroom_3 = ProjectsSerializer(many=True)
    bedroom_4 = ProjectsSerializer(many=True)
```

/views.py :

```
class MapFilter(generics.ListAPIView):

    ....

    return selected_Projects
```

where selected_projects have this struture:

```
{
    bedroom_1 : ProjectModelQuerySet,
    bedroom_2 : ProjectModelQuerySet,
    bedroom_3 : ProjectModelQuerySet,
    bedroom_4 : ProjectModelQuerySet,
}
```

where ProjectModelQuerySet is a queryset of the model Project

How I should achieve this using the Project model serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Return Image]

This is what I wanted to Serialize,

The problem was that Serializer expects an Array, So I Just put it on a List [] and that worked.